# Show/hide form contents based on radio selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im building a form that has conditional fields that need to show based on what checkboxes are selected. I want to know how I can hide other form fields when a checkbox is selected. I also want to be able to show all fields when both checkboxes are selected.

In the markup below, I have added comments where I want to render the html.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>


<!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Multiple Checkboxes</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Load">
      Load
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Unload">
      Unload
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Show when "load" is checked -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Dorms</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge">
      <option>Degraff</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Show when "load" is checked -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Greek House</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge">
      <option>Tri Delt</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Show when "unload" is checked -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">How many hops?</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge">
      <option>One</option>
      <option>Two</option>
      <option>Three</option>
      <option>Four</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Show when "unload" is checked -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">How many hours?</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge">
      <option>One</option>
      <option>Two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: To change the DOM you need some client-side language.
Use Javascript or Jquery (a javascript lib) for that

Comment: Im still grasping jquery/javascript. Any examples of this effect I can look at?

Comment: I wont give you any code, you need to understand how things work first, im just going to tell you to use jquery .hide() and .show() methods.
Try some tutorials before starting a new language from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added some `id` attributes to your elements.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>


<!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Multiple Checkboxes</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Load">
      Load
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="Unload">
      Unload
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Show when "load" is checked -->
<div id="dorms" class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Dorms</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge">
      <option>Degraff</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Show when "load" is checked -->
<div id="greek" class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">Greek House</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge">
      <option>Tri Delt</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Show when "unload" is checked -->
<div id="hops" class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">How many hops?</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge">
      <option>One</option>
      <option>Two</option>
      <option>Three</option>
      <option>Four</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Show when "unload" is checked -->
<div id="hours" class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">How many hours?</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="input-xlarge">
      <option>One</option>
      <option>Two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input[value='Load']").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $("#dorms, #greek").show();
    }else{
        $("#dorms, #greek").hide();
    }
});

    $("input[value='Unload']").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
           $("#hops, #hours").show();
        }else{
            $("#hops, #hours").hide();
        }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
#greek, #dorms, #hops, #hours{
    display:none;
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/cyTLm/

Answer (score 3):

Probably this is something that may provide you pointers on your need. You can explore more. I have made small changes in your html and using jquery(since you have tagged) and little css.

Check out the fiddle-

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

**http://jsfiddle.net/kvaYG/**

**Jquery**

```
$(':checkbox[value=Load]').change(function(){
    $('.load').toggle(); //This will get triggered during the checkbox change 
//i.e when you check or unckeck the checkbox. You can use element.toggle() 
//which will show and hide based on its last appearance whether it was shown or not. 
//This is a shortcut to using .show() and .hide()
});
    $(':checkbox[value=Unload]').change(function(){
      $('.unload').toggle();
});
```

**Css**

```
/*Initially hide all your sections*/
.load
{
    display:none;
}
.unload
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: @Mal Thanks. I thought without an explanation to a beginner no solution makes any sense.. :)