# Add child's age when child selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Very new to programming. Building a form in which asking basic questions like Age, Married or not, how many kids.
When a user selects 1 or 2 or 3 kids from the arrow keys I want to show the fields where the user can enter child's age and name. This has to be done before the submit button.
An example is hotels.com homepage where room booking option shows if you have kids and when selected asks age for all kids you selected.
Javascript would be better but willing to do it anyhow.
Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show/hide form contents based on radio selections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328576/show-hide-form-contents-based-on-radio-selections)

Comment: I am not using radio button. The input field is <input type="number" min=0 max=5 id="kids", name="kids"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have change event *(but better target both keyup and change event)* on kids textbox and do loop base on the number of child entered on that fields. Inside loop, create element and finally append the elements into result, see example below :

Suppose this is your **HTML**

```
<div>
  Child : 
  <input type="number" min="0" max="5" id="kids" name="kids"/>
</div>
<!-- display output inside this element -->
<div id="output"></div>
```

And this is your **JS**

```
$('#kids').on('change keyup', function () {      
  // get value of child(number)
  var val = $(this).val();
  // checking if entered more than 5 or any number(its depend)
  if ( val > 5 ) {
    alert('opps no more than 5');
    return;
  }
  // every time child number's updated
  // clear the container
  $('#output').empty();
  var output;
  for (var i = 0, length = val; i < length; i++) {
    output = 'Name :<input type="text" name="name"/><br/>Age : <input type="text" name="age"/><hr/>';
    // append the element
    $('#output').append(output);
  }
});
```

This is just an example, hope you get it.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/5mjz4pwr/)

Comment: works beautifully, Thanks

Comment: ouch...If I add 1 child and enter the name and age of that child and later add another child, the value of first child is lost. I need to preserve